# CentOS 7 update using "yum update" does not work

Tags: centos, upgrade

I have a VM running CentOS 7 that I have not used for a long time. Today I launched it and tried to update the CentOS system to the latest version using `yum update`, but I got a lot of errors:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
http//bay.uchicago.edu/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found Trying other mirror.
http//mirror.cs.pitt.edu/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found Trying other mirror.
http//mirror.anl.gov/pub/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden Trying other mirror.
http//mirror.pac-12.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno
14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found Trying other mirror.
http//centos.expedientevirtual.com/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found Trying other mirror.
```

(Many other similar errors are omitted ...)

```
Trying other mirror. Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  *
base: bay.uchicago.edu  * epel: csc.mcs.sdsmt.edu  * extras:
mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu  * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro  * updates:
centos-distro.cavecreek.net No packages marked for update
```

I deleted the colon after `http` in the above error messages to avoid warnings. I think these errors might come from the CentOS version I am using: 7.0.1406 -- since current latest version is a new one, say, 7.0.1588 or something, the corresponding path does not exist and hence the HTTP error 404. But how to have my current CentOS automatically adjust the path name to the latest version and be able to update from the correct URL? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try running "yum clean all" to clean all metadata?

Comment: @user1403360: Yes, it works! Could you please promote this comment as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: I wrote an answer.  I either can't or don't know how to promote the comment.

Comment: Please check the proxy settings (If your network has a proxy).

Comment: If you navigate to http://mirror.cs.pitt.edu/centos/7.0.1406/readme in your browser it says "don't use this directory anymore" FWIW...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Run the following command to clean the metadata:

```
yum clean all
```

This will clean all yum caches including cached mirrors of your yum repositories. 
On the next run it will get a new list of mirrors.

Comment: Good to see your answer. Could you expand on it a little and perhaps explain why this will resolve the OP's issue, please? That way it's more likely to be of use to other people in the future, too.

Answer (score 3):

The CentOS-Base.repo file in /etc/yum.repos may have changed since you installed.
Current mirror list is as below, with the baseurl= line commented out.

mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra

Comment: this is what i have which isnt working

Answer (score 1):

That's because that version centos-7.0.1406 is deprecated. You should use /7/ and not /7.0.1406/ in your path.

You can find your repo details in the following path.

```
/etc/yum.repos.d
```

By adding the below lines in the repo file you can point to centos 7.

```
[extrascentos7]
name=Extras packages for CentOS 7 for x86_64
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/
enabled=1
```

Answer (score 1):

set DNS to `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
*nameserver 8.8.8.8**
```

Save this file, then try `yum update` again.

Comment: yes. unexpectedly, that works :)