# CentOS 7 - No packages marked for update

Tags: centos, sudo, yum

With `yum update` I'm not able to update packages. I have tried every possible solution which is provided like `yum clean, yum repolist, etc` but none of this seems to solve this problem.

```
sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.net.in
 * elrepo: elrepo.reloumirrors.net
 * epel: mirror.nes.co.id
 * extras: mirrors.fibergrid.in
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: mirrors.fibergrid.in

No packages marked for update 


# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
#[addons]
#name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=addons&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

> NOTE - With #baseurl as well no luck.

Comment: You have an answer already that asks you to run “yum clean all”; what exactly did you run and what were the outputs?

Comment: Why do you think that you have updates available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue at Hand

You are unable to update via yum.

## Solution

I will be referencing [this stack exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210448/centos-7-update-using-yum-update-does-not-work?rq=1) as well as [this CentOS Wiki page](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) in this answer.

You are first going to need to verify that all of your repositories are correct. [The Wiki I linked](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) should have additional links to various 3rd party repositories as well as the configurations of the base repositories. I will also note, that the 3rd party repositories could potentially come into conflict with other aspects of your system. Unlike, with Debian though, I have found rpm based distros to have better support of 3rd party repos.

After you have verified that all of your repositories are configured properly, (each 3rd party/vendor should provide details as to what a working configuration file is for your respective version of CentOS) you will need to run the following command with root(sudo) permissions:

```
yum clean all
```

According to both the Wiki and user1403360, this will clear your cache and redownload your mirrors the next time your run `yum update`.

The issue is your repositories may not be correct. Remember, unlike with Debian based Distros, rpm based Distros typically require that each repository is its own file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory.

[Here is a good guide on how to manage repositories for a Redhat based system](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-managing_yum_repositories). Please verify that you have managed your repositories in the manner outlined in the link. If necessary purge all of your repositories and add them back using the outlined steps in the link.

## Conclusion

You need to make sure your repositories are managed and configured correctly, then you need to clear your cache and redownload your mirrors. This should solve your issue.

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is several years old but I just encountered it and found another workaround that worked for me.  The cause of this issue in my case was that my RHEL Subscription expired during an update.  The server's subscription was re-activated but the server continued to give the "no packages marked for update" message even though I could see that the versions on the server didn't match what Red Hat was showing on access.redhat.com for the subscription for that server.  What I discovered is that the failure happened during an update.  Yum said the packages had been all updated but the filesystem showed they in fact hadn't been updated.  Running commands like `yum clean all` did nothing for me.  What worked for me was to run:

`rpm -qa --last`

to generate the list of all packages that yum said were installed.  I then ran

`yum reinstall`

for every package to force the filesystem to match yum.

```
rpm -qa --last > /tmp/rpm-qa-last.txt
for package in `cat /tmp/rpm-qa-last.txt `; 
do 
  echo "yum reinstall $package -y" > /tmp/yum_reinstall.sh
done
chmod +x /tmp/yum_reinstall.sh
/tmp/yum_reinstall.sh
```

I also discovered that some of the repositories in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` had been disabled.  In my case, it was for Percona which provides support agreements for old versions of MySQL which is why I am updating an RHEL 7 Server in 2023.  I set `enabled=1` for the affected yum repos and when I re-ran `yum updateinfo` the new Percona packages appeared.

Note that in my case it is a RHEL Server but the same thing can happen on CentOS systems as we use both and the first part of my solution isn't specific to RHEL.